# Tables with padding do not size down?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
               <h1>Title</h1>
....close tags
```

When I add left & right padding to the `td` the cell no longer sizes down when the browser window sizes down. it'll get to a certain width of browser and the cell will no longer shrink.

I've tried adding `box-sizing: border-box;` with no luck.

Why is this happening and how can I fix?

Comment: Try a relative measurement like `2em` or `1%`

Comment: zer00ne -  why do this?

Comment: Relative measurements increase and decrease according the the parent element. `table` display types conform to it's content so if you need complete control of a `<td>`s dimension, you need to place a `<div>` or some other block element within the `<td>` and apply measurements to that.